# LEDs lighting up sequentially

Tags: led, battery-operated

I am looking for a way to light up a row of LEDs one at a time until they are all lit, about 8 to 10 LEDs, with a simple on/off switch, battery operated, and I want it to fit in a small space.

Any ideas? Or can you point me to where I can find out how to do this?

Comment: Using an arduino for this? Or are you talking about a circuit that requires no programming at all? This sounds like what's called an LED bargraph. And I think there are a number of sources -- including an IC ([LM3914](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf)?) designed for this -- where you supply an analog voltage and the appropriate LEDs light up.

Comment: Could go [here](https://tinkersphere.com/segmented-number-leds/3552-lm3914-led-bar-graph-module-green.html) and just buy one. Is that small enough for you?

Comment: Thank you jonk. I want to build it myself. With no micro controller. I am looking to fit it in a 1/2 inch PVC tube maybe 1 inch. I might just look into getting that chip, I think I have everything else. If anybody has any other suggestions or resources I'm open to all. Like I said I'm new to this. Any learning resources are welcomed as well

Comment: What kind of delay between each light? And should they all stay on steady once lit (one-shot)?

Comment: I just want a small delay ( maybe 1 second) so it's noticeable that it's lighting up from one side to the other and then just stays on until I switch it off. Not looking to use a micro controller

Answer (score 2):

8 to 10 Leds one at a time, battery operated?

A cd4017 decade counter, with a 555 timer to trigger the stepping, would do this with no coding. It's called an led chaser. See https://electrosome.com/led-chaser-ic-4017-ic-555/amp/

Alternatively, Any standard microcontroller with a very basic loop program would also work. Very common first project.

Comment: I'm looking for it to turn on and stay on. No blinking just a gradual light up and stay on till I switch it off.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Arduino, you could use a pull-down type shift register with it, such as STPIC6D595. Arduino-specific instructions:
https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/communication/guide-to-shift-out

If you are not planning to add more features, there's no reason to use anything else than a chip such as LM3914. Currently Arduino compatible microcontrollers are difficult to source too, if you were planning to implement it on a custom board rather than using an Arduino-module.

Answer (score 1):

The LM3914 (with some kind of analog ramp input) is probably your best bet within the given constraints.

---

Another option that doesn't involve oddball ICs would be something like 3x LM324 and 20 or so resistors, plus a circuit for the ramp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWOfnn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

---

If you were to use something like an [STM8S](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_DnMzyvh) "Arduino" (18mm wide PCB) it would be very easy, just 10 resistors and a few lines of code. You'd need an [STLINK](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_DDcDmYX) for this kind of board though, unlike Arduino nano etc. which are programmed through the USB port. Here is one driving a 10-LED battery gauge:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, using CD4049 CMOS inverter gates. Starting with just 4 LEDs.
I omitted current limit resistors since the gates have inherent output current limiting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ4TDY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the same idea, expanded to eight (8) LEDs. I added LED-series resistors to make the simulation closer to reality. But if you operate the circuit from 5 volts -- & not higher -- then you my need not need them since the CD4049 will limit its output current to approximately 6 mA.

[image: 8_LED_version]